# Как автоматически изменить названия однотипных полей?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jenkins

Сейчас в 100 классах есть объявление:

```
public final static Log log = ...
```

Дженкинс в разделе "инспекция кода" выдает, соответственно лишних 100 предупреждений, советуя исправить стиль написания на заглавные буквы (если будет что-то действительно важное, мне будет сложнее заметить среди всего этого безобразия).

Использую Intellij IDEA. Если включить глобальную замену по выражению выше, то автоматически изменяется лишь объявление таких логгеров, а **использования** в коде такой режим не учитывает, из-за чего сразу же возникает много ошибок.

Подскажите, как лучше выполнить замену, чтобы она не затронула локальные переменные `log`, либо имеющие такой префикс?

Answer (score 2):

нотепад++ поиск-> замена -найти в файлах и заменить одно выражение на другое.галочку учитывать регистр выбрать.

Comment: `log` - часто используемая комбинация символов, если будет такая же локальная переменная, то она тоже заменится, получается

Comment: А если регулярным выражением, добавив пробелы до и после слова?

Comment: нашел опцию "поиск по целым словам"